# Including a the JTattoo LAF in an Application

Tags: java, jar, look-and-feel

I am new to Java and I have searched the web and Java Documentation a lot, but I don't understand how to integrate JTatto LAF in my Application.

I downloaded the .jar file and saved it into the same folder where my classes are.
The code to integrate looks like this.:

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.smart.SmartLookAndFeel");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("An Exception occured: "+e);
}
```

But it always returns me an `ClassNotFound-Exception`.

I even tried to integrate the source into the folder of my classes:
I donwloaded the source and copied the com\jtattoo\plaf folder into the folder of my classes.
Then I try to import it via

```
import com.jtattoo.plaf.*;
```

This seems to work, but I still can't set the LAF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that JTattoo.jar is in your CLASSPATH. I'm not familiar with your editor, but it probably has a "project" setting that will allow you to specify .jar files that should be in the CLASSPATH at runtime.

Outside of your IDE, just make sure you have it set via `java -classpath "./JTattor.jar:...other jars:" my.MainClass`, etc.

If you set the CLASSPATH correctly, you won't need to integrate the source code into your own project.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Custom Class Libraries** in BlueJ is explained **[here](http://www.bluej.org/help/archive.html#tip5)**

> The first way is via the "Preferences" dialog. Open the
> "Preferences" dialogue and select the "Libraries" tab. Then add the
> location where your classes/jar are as a library path. Restart BlueJ -
> done.
> The selected libraries will now be available in all projects
> that you open.
> [...]